# I want to trigger an event from clicking on a date in jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, datepicker

I'm working on a site that uses jQuery datepicker. It works as a kind of wizard, where first you pick a service, then you pick an available date, then you pick an available time. As it stands, the 'next' button shows when datepicker's calendar intiates, and I'd like to keep it hidden until a date is picked. I've included a div called 'choose_a_date' as the point where I'd like it to hold until, well, a date is chosen.

jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#date_panel,#time_panel,#confirm_panel').hide();
        $(".booking").click(function(){
        $('#svc_panel').fadeIn(function(){
        $('#date_panel,#time_panel,#confirm_panel').hide();

        });
    });


      $(".date_button").click(function(){
            $('#svc_panel,#time_panel,#confirm_panel,').hide();
            $('#date_panel').fadeIn(function(){
            });
      });

      $('.time_button').click(function(){
            $('#svc_panel,#date_panel,#confirm_panel').hide();
            $('#time_panel').fadeIn(function(){
            });
      });

      $('.confirm_button').click(function(){
            $('#svc_panel,#date_panel,#time_panel').hide();
            $('#confirm_panel').fadeIn(function(){
            });
      });

  });

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="date_panel">

                        <p>Choose a date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>

                        <div id="wait_for_date"><a href="#"  class="time_button">Next</a></div>

                    </div>

                    <div id="time_panel">

                        <div>Choose a time on: <span id="target"></span></div>

                        <table>

                            <tr>

                                <td class="confirm_button"><a href="#">11:30 am</a></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>

                                <td class="confirm_button"><a href="#">12:30 pm</a></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>

                                <td class="confirm_button"><a href="#">2:00 pm</a></td>

                            </tr>

                        </table>

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation for the [onSelect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) event

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { ... }
});
```

Comment: Plus one for adding the link, yet I'm not sure exactly what to do with it. See my comment below for elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

Datepicker has `onSelect` which is called when a date is selected.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { ... }
});
```

Comment: It appears you and Mike Ruhlin have come to the same conclusion. Now, pardon my noob-ness, but what goes in the curlies in place of the ellipses?

Comment: You put whatever you want to do when a date is select.  Anything at all, hide something, show something, etc.